# uncaught exception in jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I have this JSF tabs with JQuery and AJAX. But there is a bug that I cannot find. This is the JSF page:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>DX-57 History Center</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/css/themes/nvidia.com/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="resources/css/helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/css/dropdown.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/css/default.advanced.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
        <link href="resources/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/mytabs.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_application.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:650px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">


                        <h:form prependId="false">
                            <h:panelGroup id="tabs" layout="block">
                                <ul>
                                    <c:forEach items="#{ApplicationController.tabs}" var="tab">
                                        <li><a href="##{tab.tabid}" onclick="$('#button_#{tab.tabid}').click()">#{tab.tabid}</a></li>
                                        <h:commandButton id="button_#{tab.tabid}" value="TabClick" action="#{ApplicationController.switchPages(tab.tabid)}" style="display:none">
                                            <f:ajax render="tabs"></f:ajax>
                                        </h:commandButton>  
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </ul>

                                <c:forEach items="#{ApplicationController.tabs}" var="tab">
                                    <h:panelGroup id="#{tab.tabid}" layout="block" rendered="#{tab.tabid eq ApplicationController.selectedTab}">
                                        <ui:include src="#{tab.tabfilename}"></ui:include>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:form>


                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   

            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;   

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("ApplicationController")
@SessionScoped
public class Application implements Serializable {

    public Application() {
    }
    /* Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tabs = new ArrayList<MyTabObject>();
        tabs.add(new MyTabObject("ApplicationTabMain.xhtml", "Main"));
        tabs.add(new MyTabObject("ApplicationTabModel.xhtml", "Model"));
        tabs.add(new MyTabObject("ApplicationTabSettings.xhtml", "Settings"));

    }
    String selectedTab = "Main";

    public String getSelectedTab() {
        return selectedTab;
    }

    public void setSelectedTab(String selectedTab) {
        this.selectedTab = selectedTab;
    }

    public String switchPages(String selTab) {
        selectedTab = selTab;
        return "Application.xhtml";
    }
    List<MyTabObject> tabs;

    public List<MyTabObject> getTabs() {
        return tabs;
    }

    public void setTabs(List<MyTabObject> tabs) {
        this.tabs = tabs;
    }

    ////
    public class MyTabObject {

        String tabfilename;
        String tabid;

        public String getTabfilename() {
            return tabfilename;
        }

        public void setTabfilename(String tabfilename) {
            this.tabfilename = tabfilename;
        }

        public String getTabid() {
            return tabid;
        }

        public void setTabid(String tabid) {
            this.tabid = tabid;
        }

        public MyTabObject(String tabfilename, String tabid) {
            super();
            this.tabfilename = tabfilename;
            this.tabid = tabid;
        }
    }
}
```

The JSF page has these tabs:

ApplicationTabMain.xhtml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:form>
                    Main
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

ApplicationTabModel.xhtml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:form>
                    Model
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

ApplicationTabSettings.xhtml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:form>
                    Settings
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

For now I have only plain JSF tabs without any Java code. This is the problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The content of the tabs is not displayed. In firebug I get this error:

```
uncaught exception: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.
```

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Using a decent JSF UI component library like PrimeFaces or RichFaces saves you from this kind of problems and a lot of time waste because you're attempting to homebrew it yourself (or letting others do..) with poor basic HTML/CSS/JS/JSF knowledge.

Comment: Nice with so much information, but the actual rendered html would also be useful.

Comment: This is the HTML code: http://pastebin.com/SNNx2pMy

Comment: @BalusC can you tell me is it possible to implement pure JSF tabs with AJAX and Lazy loading? I found example which shows that JSF tabs can be implemented but without AJX and lazy loading.

Comment: Surely it's possible. PrimeFaces for example has already done it for you in flavor of `<p:tabView>` component. See also the [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewDynamic.jsf).

Comment: Yes but I want (if it's possible) to use pure JSF code

Comment: PrimeFaces also uses pure JSF/jQuery code. It's open source. Download and check its source code.

Comment: For start , since you are using sessionscope beans turn all your public String switchPages... methods into void and delete the return statement in that methods , Second , how many jquery files are included in your page eventually ??? check that with firebug or your browser dev tools

Comment: I edited the code this way: http://pastebin.com/siMC6i4T. The tabs are working. I don't know why and how! The problem is that I still get this error in Firebug: uncaught exception: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier. What this mean?

Comment: This question has an accepted answer which indicates that it solved your problem. But your bounty indicates the otherwise. Is your problem solved or not? If not, why is the current single answer accepted? What exactly have you tried based on the answer and how exactly does it *not* solve your problem?

Comment: Well, the example works but I still get this error in Firebug - uncaught exception: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.

Comment: @PeterPenzov are you using several jquery files ? or maybe some library that you are using got old jquery inside it ?

Comment: I use version jquery-1.7.2.min

Comment: it was working at start... right? think what you have added to it later on... does it work fine in chrome /IE ?

Comment: I can send you the prototype source code in order to see more closely how it works

Comment: unfortunately i can't a.t.m , but i strongly recommend you to compare between the clean version and the modified  one....

Answer (score 5):

There are indications you may use incompatible jquery/jqueryui versions according to this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/uncaught-exception-jquery-ui-tabs-mismatching-fragment-identifier-5-2-2010

Try switching back to jquery 1.3.2 if you are not already.